# JQuery ajax stop urlencode of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a webapp and have to get data from several APIs to show the user. So in the first step the user can select several places I get from the first api. There I get coordinates like 1.2345,6.7890 and I save them to a array. Now I want to pass them to a routing-api and the parameters have to be http://example.com/route?location=1.2345,6.7890&location=2.3456,7.8901.

The problem is jQuery encodes the data and switches the , to %2C. The Google-API accepts both versions but the API I have to use only accepts , .

```
myPlaces = ["1.2345,6.7890", "2.3456,7.8901"]

$.ajax({
    url : "example.com",
    datatype : "json",
    jsonp : "jsonp",
    data : {
        loc : myPlaces
    }
});
```

How do I tell jQuery not to encode my data strings?

Comment: worst case you can manually construct the query string rather than pass an object to `data`

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, you'll have to manually compose your input string, as jQuery's parameter serialization will always auto URL-encode your commas .

Luckily, this shouldn't be too much of a headache:

```js
myPlaces = ["1.2345,6.7890", "2.3456,7.8901"];

//string composition function

var placesString = myPlaces.reduce(function(str, current){
  return str + "loc=" + current;
}, "");
    
//then use it in your ajax call

$.ajax({
    url : "example.com",
    datatype : "json",
    jsonp : "jsonp",
    data : placesString,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems to be urlencoded differently in different browsers (Firefox doesn't encode but  Chrome does). Try to map the coordinates into the url directly instead:

```
myPlaces = ["1.2345,6.7890", "2.3456,7.8901"];

var myPlacesQueryString = "";
$.each(myPlaces, function(i, value) {
    myPlacesQueryString += "location=" + value;
    if (i < myPlaces.length - 1) {
        myPlacesQueryString += "&";
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url : "example.com/route?" + myPlacesQueryString,
    datatype : "json",
    jsonp : "jsonp"
});
```